# How can i fix "Uncaught TypeError: dispatch is not a function"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, redux

I am encountering this error: "Uncaught TypeError: dispatch is not a function", when trying to execute a dispatch action on the window.

I double checked the syntax.

```
Uncaught TypeError: dispatch is not a function
    at Object.eval (spot_actions.js?27ea:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1:3412)
    at fire (jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1:3233)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1:3363)
    at done (jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1:9841)
    at XMLHttpRequest.callback (jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1:10312)
```

```
export const fetchAllSpots = () => dispatch => (
    APIUtil.fetchAllSpots().then(spots => 
    dispatch(receiveAllSpots(spots)))
);

const receiveAllSpots = payload => ({
    type: RECEIVE_ALL_SPOTS,
    payload
});
```

```
window.fetchAllSpots = fetchAllSpots();
```

Comment: Here is the util call function:export const fetchAllSpots = () => (
  $.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/api/spots',
  })
);

Comment: you have not defined dispatch as function

Comment: could you elaborate on that? thank you!

Comment: have you wired redux-thunk as a middleware to your redux store ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you adding `dispatch` to the router connect?
Something like :

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, dispatch => ({
  dispatch, ComponentNameHere})) (ComponentNameHere)
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure to install `redux-thunk` as a middleware and apply it to `store`

- https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk#installation
- https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk#composition